# FHIR _id to id change in newest code

Tags: java, mongodb, hl7-fhir

After downloading and building FHIR revision 2833 yesterday, I noticed several differences between the new Java code and the last released code, FHIR version 0.81.

1. 12 new resources have been defined.  Where would I find documentation or design discussions concerning these resources and their use cases?
2. An important key name in the JSON representation has changed.  "**_id**" has been changed to "**id**".  I suspect many applications use the _id field to identify resource instances, create indexes on that field, and have application code that references that field by name.

   1. What was the rationale for changing the name of this field?
   2. Are there release notes that document changes since version 0.81?
   3. Should the change also be propagated to line 561 in JsonComposerBase.java?
3. Since the next release encompasses so many changes, it might be a good time to upgrade the external libraries on which FHIR depends, including:

   1. xpp3:  latest =  1.1.4.c, current FHIR = 1.1.3.4.O
   2. gson:  latest = 2.3, current FHIR = 2.2.4
   3. common-codec:  latest = 1.9, current FHIR = 1.3
4. As I was debugging the migration to the new FHIR code, I had a hard time tracking down the cause of parse errors.  Is there a debug setting that would expose where a parse failed?  Augmenting the error message on line 6811 in JsonParser.java to include the unknown resource type that was encountered would help in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have downloaded the java code from the trunk. This is the
   development version of FHIR, published here: http://latest.fhir.me/.
   I'm about to release a new version of java reference implementation
   for DSTU (including updating maven) - in the next 48 hours or so. Watch
   http://www.healthintersections.com.au for the announcement.
2. This was a bug in the Java code against the specification. See http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/json.html. The Java
   Reference implementation was wrong, and had to fixed against this. I
   have not done release notes for this yet - I will be doing that
   shortly (see #1). And, yes, the changes should be line 561 of
   JsonComposeBase - thanks, I missed this when migrating the changes
   from the DSTU fork to trunk
3. I have updated the references, thanks (1.1.4c for xpp)
4. I have improved the error message, thanks

Comment: Thanks, Grahame.  I notice that familyhistory-genetics-profile-annie-example.json still uses the _id key.  Also, the json-edge-cases.json file fails to parse on the "gender" field.  Here's the stack trace:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
 at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)
 at org.hl7.fhir.instance.formats.JsonParser.parsePatient(JsonParser.java:4609)
 at org.hl7.fhir.instance.formats.JsonParser.parseResource(JsonParser.java:6774)